# div tag doesn't have a name attribute but I need it for form.post

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am making a drop-down button which contains the languages I have so that I can pass this language (the chosen) to the view but apparently there is not a name attribute so I don't know what to do can anyone please help me.

here is what I'm trying to do

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="languageForm">{% csrf_token %}
                                            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
                                            <div class="dropdown show">
                                                  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    Language
                                                  </a>

                                                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" name="language" id="selectLanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                                      {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                                                      {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                                                      {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                                                      {% for language in languages %}

                                                      <a class="dropdown-item"  value="{{ language.code }}"
                                                            {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                                                        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})</a>


                                                      {% endfor %}
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Go">-->
                                        </form>
```

Edit: I added a hidden input and called a javasript function when item change but nothing happened

```js
function changeLang(e) {
    document.getElementById("selectLanguage").value = e.target.value;
    document.getElementById("languageForm").submit();
        alert(e.target.value);
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="languageForm">{% csrf_token %}
                                            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
                                            <div class="dropdown show">
                                                  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="lang_btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    Language
                                                  </a>

                                                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" name="language" id="selectLanguage">
                                                      {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                                                      {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                                                      {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                                                      {% for language in languages %}

                                                       <input type="hidden"  id="selectLanguage" name="language" value="">

                                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href=""  value="{{ language.code }}" onchange="changeLang(event)"
                                                            {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                                                        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})</a>


                                                      {% endfor %}
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Go">-->
                                            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Go">-->
                                        </form>
```

Comment: Use a hidden input and change the value of that input with JavaScript via an change listener on your dropdown.

Comment: I am so sorry but I have another question. so in dropdown menu I have onchange="this.form.submit()" should I remove it and call my new function that I'm going to write or should I call it in <a class="dropdown-item" tag?

Comment: You should call the form submit from the function you're going to write.

Comment: can you please check the edit @NoahBoegli